# Does a trait exist for generic code for references and values without having to write it all out twice?

Tags: generics, rust, reference, traits

I have a trait implemented for iterators over `&u64`, but sometimes I want to use it with an iterator that produces `u64`. I'm wondering if there's a way to implement my trait for both `T` and `&T` without having to write it all out twice. I think it is equivalent to this problem:

```rust
pub fn foo<T: RefOrValue<i32>>(t: T) {
    let x: i32 = t.to_value();
    // ...
}

pub fn main() {
    foo(1i32);
    foo(&2i32);
}
```

Does a trait like `RefOrValue` exist?

Comment: The specific example doesn't really call for a generic type -- I gave justifications for that in my answer to [Opposite of Borrow trait for a Copy type in Rust?](/q/63465672/3650362) But in the general case where the type is non-`Copy` and the function actually only needs a reference, `Borrow` is the way to go.